# How do you check dates with pits on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, fruits, bugs, inspection, borer-separating

Dates may contain insects and should be checked before consuming ([source](http://www.crcweb.org/NewFruitandVeglist.pdf)). The only way to do this (that I am aware of) for dates with pits is to open the date and remove the pit to examine the area underneath it. Doing this would seem to be a problem of [borer](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Borer) on Shabbat. I would like to know

1. Is this in fact a problem of borer and if not, why not?
2. If this is a problem of borer, what is the halachically advisable way of checking a date on shabbat (or is it not possible)?

Comment: Why not just take the good from the bad (just prior to use without specialized equipment)? Maybe I'm missing something. Open the date. Take the flesh. Check it. Eat it.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know if you've ever eaten a date with a pit but in my experience doing so is not possible because of how sticky the flesh is. I am literally trying to do it right now and failing.

Comment: Why does sticky matter? Don't take the pit from the flesh. Take the flesh from the pit.